# Bind qt quick qml to c++

Tags: c++, qt, function, qml

I want to bind qt qml code to c++ functions and c++ source file.
How can I run c++ function directly from qml code for example button onClick event?
And how can I call a function from a c++ source file in qml for example onClick event?
plz explain more and more! I'm beginner.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500280/access-c-function-from-qml

Comment: **This Question Doesnt Need Code Example**

Answer (score 2):

There are several options.

1. A C++ class that can be instantiated from QML, see [Access C++ function from QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500280/access-c-function-from-qml) as KimKulling pointed out in a comment
2. A C++ class instantiated in C++ and exposed to the QML engine via `QQmlContext::setContextProperty()`, see my answer on [I have multiple qml Files that get pushed via StackView. How do I connect them to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847939/i-have-multiple-qml-files-that-get-pushed-via-stackview-how-do-i-connect-them-t/41848943) for that technique
3. A C++ class instantiated once in C++ and used as a "QML Singleton" via `qmlRegisterSingleton()`

Answer (score -1):

You should read the official [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) on signals and slots.

Basically, you are assigning a C++ function to a signal. If the signal is catched, it calls the function.